# How to access the view of a UITableViewRowAction iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8

I have implemented some edit actions for the rows of a table view using `UITableViewRowAction`. One of them is a delete action and i want to present a popover containing an action sheet to confirm the delete action. Thus, I need a reference to the delete button view to pass it to the `UIPopoverPresentationController`.

There is any way to access the view of the `UITableViewRowAction` object?

To clarify a bit more, the view im trying to access is the red delete button, marked in green:

[image]

Comment: Swift or Objective C?

Comment: @derdida Prefer Objective C, but can understand both

Comment: The indexPath of the cell you swiped on is passed to the handler. Isn't that all you need?

Comment: @rdelmar I want the rectangular red view containing the "delete" button, so i can pass it to the popover controller.

Comment: @derdida: did you ever find a solution for this? I would also like to do this. Thanks

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't know the Objective-C version of this, but I'm using this in a project of mine right now in Swift, and it should work. It's iOS 8 only though, I'm not sure there's a way to do it prior to that.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {

    var deleteButton: UITableViewRowAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "       ", handler: { (action, indexPath) in

            // put whatever you need to call here. below is the default code, which will delete the cell as usual. 
            self.tableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
                self.tableView,
                commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
                forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath

            )

            return
        })
    }
    return [deleteButton]
}
```

Your other option is to use the tableview function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Where you could create a popup and let them confirm it. That would probably work better actually, I believe that's exactly the kind of thing that function is for.

Edit: forgot the return [deleteButton] in that first bit of code.

Answer (score -1):

UIView *view = sender.superview; //Cell contentView

```
CustomCell *cell; // (you can custom tableviewcell name if created)
if(SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(@"8.0"))
{
    cell = (CustomCell *)view.superview;
}
else{
    cell = (CustomCell *)[[[sender superview] superview]superview];

}

And Access it by :-
cell.view
```